# CouchDB query list not giving any result

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

I am trying to query in couchDB to filter with code ='hi'

```
{
id:1,
linked": {
  "type": "XX",
  "code": [
   "hi",
   "hello"
  ]
 }
```

This is how I am trying:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "linked": {
         "type": "xx",
         "$elemMatch": {
            "code": "hi"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am not getting output.Can anybody help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the intention of your query correctly, I think you mean:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "linked.type": "XX",
      "linked.code": {
         "$elemMatch": {
            "$eq": "hi"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

- to access sub-objects of your document use "dot notation" e.g. linked.type
- the equality operator is case sensitive. "XX" not "xx"
- the `$elemMatch` operator was specified incorrectly. See [the docs here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#the-elemmatch-operator)